# Android Kotlin Material Slider Update Int Value

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, slider, seekbar

I have two activities (MainActivity, SecondActivity). In secondActivity I have a material slider.

```
var powerLevel = 0
val slider: Slider? = findViewById(R.id.slider)

slider?.addOnChangeListener(Slider.OnChangeListener { slider, _, _ ->
    
// Not sure what to do here:
MainActivity.powerLevel = slider.value.toString()

})
```

In MainActivity I have a variable: **powerLevel** = 125. I want to update the value of **foo.currentPower(powerLevel)** as the user increases/decreases the slider.

Tried a bunch of things online, but most just showed how to get the new value and put it to a textView instead of actually making any usable changes.

Comment: You're asking about passing data between Activities - there are lots of questions (and solutions!) about that on the site. In your case, you might want to store your current value in `SharedPreferences` when the listener fires, and have the other `Activity` read from that in `onResume` or something. Really if you can, you should consider moving to a single-Activity app and using `Fragment`s and `ViewModel`s - it makes it a lot easier to share data like this, and have changes in one place reflected in another

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I know how to use sharedPreferences. Just don't know how to have my value which is set in the app change along with the slider as a user moves it.

Comment: If the slider and the variable are in two different Activities, those two separate Activities don't run at the same time, so you can't get "live" updates anyway. So like I said, you need to store your updated value somewhere they can both access, like SharedPreferences, and have MainActivity read from that when it resumes, so it can update its local variable